# Ошибка "Не установлена конечная платформа проекта"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Решил открыть проект, у тут он не открывается, вот такой поворот :3

При этом сам проект до этого был создан именно в этой Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 и всё прекрасно работало,если выйти и снова запустить VS2010 то проект уже не открывается. В интернете ответов не нашёл.Да и не понятна сама ошибка , что там так ломается ??? (в QtСreatore такого мракобесия нету )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить ??

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Проверьте на наличие приемлемой версии .NET

**2.** При отсутствии или несовместимости версий, попробуйте установить с официального сайта. https://www.microsoft.com/ru-RU/download/details.aspx?id=56116

UPD: Так как у вас Windows 7 стоит, то рекомендую не устанавливать самую свежую версию, скорее всего Вам нужна версия 4.5 Net.

Comment: Ох, я в воскресенье и с помощью "клинера" стал руками папки удалять, на компе оказалось VS2010  VS2015  VS2017 (эпоха бурной деятельности ). А самое бессовестное что при попытки удалить их с компа он пытается к серверу приконектиться **будто бы я гость в собственном доме** и это меня с бесило почему я и руками стал удалять.